# How to break next line execution without checking using if else?

Tags: jquery, module

`defaultManager()` calls `login()` function to check if user has logged in. The login will return either `true` or `false`. Is there a way where the `login()` function can stop further execution of `defaultManager()` if login is `false`?

Returning `false` will only stop whatever is beneath the `login` function itself, but I want to stop whatever is beneath the call made to `login()` in `defaultManager()`.

The available method is, storing value returned by login and use if..else to determine steps to be taken. But I prefer not to use if else..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {     
    var myModule =  (function(sendTo) {    
        var self = {
            init: function() {    
                self.defaultManager();                      
            },    
            login: function() {                     
                var userId = this.getSetting('userId');    
                if (userId < 0) {
                    return false;
                }    
                return true;
            },    
            getSetting: function(requiredSetting) {    
                var settings  = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('conversekitGlobalSettings'));
                return settings[requiredSetting];
            },    
            defaultManager: function() {
               //i prefer not to do this
               var login =this.login();

               if (login == 1) {
                  //do this
               } else {
                  //do this
               }

                //is this can be done?
               this.login();
               //must not execute whatever written here if call
               //to the login() is false                         
            }
        };    
        return self;            
    })(interface);    
    myModule.init();
});
```

Comment: You've already called `login()` once from within `defaultManager()` and have an `if` condition depending on it's result. Just put the logic you want to execute in the correct section of the `if` statement...? Also use `if(login)` not `if (login == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

One sort of trick is to use the AND operator (`&&`) as a shortcut, and wrap the remainder stuff you want to get executed in a function. The && operator only executes the right hand side if the left hand side returns a thruthy value.

```
login() && whenLoggedIn();

function whenLoggedIn(){
  // do stuff when login has returned true
}
```

But really not much wrong with an if else in your case I think. This trick for example does not pass a (strict) jslint check, because you don't have a statement or assignment on that first line.